# Django. CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have just recently started learning Django.
I have a problem with the password change page

403
Reason given for failure:
CSRF token missing or incorrect.

My users/urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
path(
  'logout/',
  LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logged_out.html'),
  name='logout'
),
path( 
  'login/',
  LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),
  name='login'
),
path( 
  'password_change/',
  PasswordChangeView.as_view(template_name='users/password_change_form.html'),
  name='password_change_form'
),
path( 
  'password_change/done/',
  PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_change_done.html'),
  name='password_change_done'
),
...,
]
```

And My Form in Template starts

```
<form method="post"
  {% if action_url %}
    action="{% url action_url %}"
  {% endif %}
>
  {% csrf_token %}
  <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">
```

With this form, I get the error 403 and "CSRF token missing or incorrect."

Without this string everythink works

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">
```

everythink works.
1)Could you please explain me why? And what is it?
What is the best way to use csrf?
2) I also used to write like

```
 <form method="post" action="{% url 'users:password_change_form' %}">
```

But founded this example using action_url.
What is action_url?
What way is better?

Answer (score 1):

action is the attribute in the form tag. and "action_url" is the URL(a page) it goes to when you click on submit button. So you need to define that URL there. and the correct syntax in Django is :

```
<form action={% url 'process' %}  method="POST">
```

So here process is name of that URL you define in urls.py file.
Something like this :

```
path('process/', views.process, name='process')
```

And in order to work you need to have that file in your app.

So in your case type the name of your URL you've defined in ulrs.py file in if condition.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to use only:

   {% csrf_token %}

instead of

```
{% csrf_token %}
 <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="">
```

I'm afraid that the second line of code overwritten the csrf_token value.

2. 'action' in the form specifies where to send the form-data when a form is submitted. In this case, after the form is submitted, it will go to 'users' app, url name 'password_change_form', then pass to the view associated with it.

Comment: 1) yes, it works with only `{% csrf_token %}` But I can't get why so, what is hidden input `type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value=""` 
2) I want to know more about action_url variable, what is it? Not action=some_url

Comment: 1)  `{% csrf_token %}` will be automatically converted to `type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="somesecretkey"`. You can verify this by inspecting the webpage. Those hidden input will be POST to the targeted url in the form of dictionary, in this case, {csrfmiddlewaretoken:"somesecretkey"}. You can proof this via printing request.POST.get('csrfmiddlewaretoken') in the views.py.

2) I believe 'action_url' is the name of one of your url declared in url.py, right?

Comment: no, i have no url with name 'action_url'. 
I use 'action_url' in templates where path like `path('url', some ClassBasedView from django.contrib.auth.views, name='some_name')` . But I didn't used name 'action url' for any url in any urls.py